# Oracle SQL displaying 100% as 0%

Tags: sql, oracle, percentage

I have a query that shows percentage of a job being to completion. Here is my query:

NVL(substr(countprocess_locations.count_attempt_id)/count(processes.process_id),2,2),0)||'%' as "Percentage Complete"

Everything has worked fine and beautifully, BUT I recently had a count hit 100% mathematically, but in the output of the query it says 0. I've tried playing with 2,2),0 and no difference so far :/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sample

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a working example breaking it down.

159 / 180 = 0.883333

SUBSTR first converts it to text, when doing so Oracle drops the leading zero

.883333

SUBSTR then takes two characters starting at the second

.**88**3333

Then you concatenate '%' to it

88%

When you have 100% it flows such:

2000 / 2000 = 1

Converts to text

1

Takes two characters starting at the second

NULL

Then your NVL returns 0.

Instead of SUBSTR you should * 100 and then ROUND or if you really want to just drop the digits instead of rounding use TRUNC.

```
NVL(ROUND((countprocess_locations.count_attempt_id)/count(processes.process_id))*100,0),0)||'%'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, I just had to move left parenthesis from after ROUND to after count, and remove lingering right parenthesis after process_id) from your input other than late worked like a charm! THANKS! NVL(ROUND(count(process_locations.count_attempt_id)/count(_processes._process_id)*100,0),0)||'%' as "Percentage Complete"

Comment: Excellent, sorry about the bracket, I wasn't connected to test, my bad.